# Python sort a list by most comment element

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples and I need to sort it by the most common element. This function works fine with lists of simple types, but with tuples I run into this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
def counts(self, a_list):
    hist = {}
    for x in a_list:
        entry = hist.get(x, 0)
        hist[x] = entry+1
    return hist
```

---

After spending all together too much time on this problem, I realized my program is rather confusing and twisted. Hence I have started some major refactoring and this problem is no longer relevant.

Comment: Its probably best if you show us the function you wrote that works with simple types

Comment: @deathApril: mutable objects are not hashable as a rule: [`hash([])`](http://ideone.com/0HgzK)

Comment: You could cast the tuple to a string and hash based on that?

Comment: looks like your tuples may actually be lists.  try adding `x = tuple(x)` on a new line just after the `for`.  that will force them to be tuples (which can be hashed).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - i thought about using any hash function in the custom sort ;)) now the code shows OP is using hash (hist[x]) - but it should be ok for tuples, only bad for list of lists..

Comment: ps in case it's not clear tuples are made with parens `(1,2)` (and are immutable) while lists use brackets `[1,2]` and can have their contents changed (which is why they can't be used used in maps, because they could be changed while they were inside, causing confusion).

Comment: @andrewcooke My list does contain tuples, but some of those lists contain lists. I'm not sure if that will make a difference.

Comment: yes, that will cause a problem too.  it's because the hash is calculated recursively - the hash of a tuple is a function of the hash of each thing it contains.  and so you have the same problem - a list cannot occur anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If your list contains other lists you could convert nested lists to tuples first before counting:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(list_of_tuples).most_common())
print(Counter(map(tuple, list_of_lists)).most_common())
```

Comment: Normally this is what I would use, however the Counter class was added in python 2.7 and for this project I have to stick to 2.6.

Comment: @giodamelio: you could use `d = defaultdict(int) \n for item in list_of_tuples: d[item]+=1 \n list_of_tuples.sort(key=d.get, reverse=True)`

Comment: @giodamelio: it seems you don't understand the difference between a list and a tuple. If you have list of lists (one level deep i.e., there are no grandchildren lists) then you could convert it to list of tuples as shown in my answer above i.e., `list_of_tuples = map(tuple, list_of_lists)`. If it doesn't help then serialize children before counting: `list_of_strings = map(str, list_of_deeply_nested_lists)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def counts(self, a_list):
    hist = {}
    for x in a_list:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            x = tuple(x)
        entry = hist.get(x, 0)
        hist[x] = entry+1
    return hist
```